# error LNK2019: "unresolved external symbol" using variadic function

Tags: templates, variadic

Trying to build function that gets unknown number of arguments.

Header.h:

```
void WriteHeaderToCSVFile() {}

template <typename FieldType, typename... Types>
void WriteHeaderToCSVFile(FieldType field1, Types...field2);
```

Source.cpp:

```
template <typename FieldType, typename... Types>
void CSVWriter::WriteHeaderToCSVFile(FieldType field1, Types... field2)
{
    mFileStream->Write(field1);
    mFileStream->Write(scComma);
    WriteHeaderToCSVFile(field2...);
}

void main()
{
   myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(L("no.record"), L("no.page"), L("values"));
}
```

Getting the error bellow:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl CSVWriter::WriteHeaderToCSVFile<wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *>(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (??$WriteHeaderToCSVFile@PEB_WPEB_WPEB_W@XMPCSVWriter@@QEAAXPEB_W00@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl TestCSVFileWriter(void)" (?TestCSVFileWriter@@YAXXZ)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that you need an "empty" overload for `WriteHeaderToCSVFile()` as ground case for the recursion; I mean

```
void CSVWriter::WriteHeaderToCSVFile ()
{ }
```

I mean... `myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(L("no.record"), L("no.page"), L("values"));` call `myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(L("no.page"), L("values"));` that matches the variadic method (`L("no.page")` matches `field1`, `L("values")` matches `field2...`)

Then `myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(L("no.page"), L("values"));` call `myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(L("values"));` that matches the variadic method (`L("values")` matches `field1`, `field2...` matches as empty).

The `myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(L("values"));` call `myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile();` but nothing matches `field1`, for the variadic method.

So you need another `WriteHeaderToCSVFile()` that can match an empty list of argument.

Off Topic Unrequested Suggestion: define your templates (classes, functions, methods, variables, etc.) directly in the header files where they are declared.

The reason is well described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thank you
Tried that and now the error is:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl CSVWriter::WriteHeaderToCSVFile<int,int,int>(int,int,int)"

Change the call in main to:
myFile2.WriteHeaderToCSVFile(1,2,3);

Comment: @טלהיינה - Sorry but, without a complete example (possibly minimal), to reproduce the error, is very difficult to say where the problem is.